# Flutter multipart image no sending with the rest of the body

Tags: flutter, dart, http, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm trying to send a multipart request using the flutter http package and so far, every field is sent successfully, except the image. The code is below.

```
Future multipartPostRequestProfile(
      id, dob, country, state, gender, File? imgPath) async {
    var token = await storage.read(key: 'jwt');
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'PUT', Uri.parse('url'));

    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      "image",
      imgPath!.path,
    ));
    request.fields['dateOfBirth'] = dob;
    request.fields['country'] = country;
    request.fields['state'] = state;
    request.fields['gender'] = gender;

    request.headers.addAll({
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
    });
    var res = await request.send();
    var result = await http.Response.fromStream(res);

    if (result.statusCode != 200)
      return {'result': result.statusCode, 'body': result.body};
    final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = jsonDecode(result.body);
    return responseData;
  }
```

Comment: your code is correct I think problem is in your request method type like may be its POST method not PUT . or problem may be exist in field name of image

Comment: Hello, could you provide a little more context to the question. What is the error message or result that you are getting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this..method

```
Future multipartRequestPost(
String url,
String methodName, {
required Map<String, String> header,
File? image1,
File? image2,
Map<String, String>? body,
String? image1Key,
String? image2Key,
  }) async {
    var client = http.Client();
    try {
     String fullURL = APIUrl.baseUrl + url;
     var request = http.MultipartRequest(methodName, 
   Uri.parse(fullURL));
  if (body != null) {
    request.fields.addAll(body);
  }
  if (image1?.path.isNotEmpty ?? false) {
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(image1Key ?? '', 
    image1?.path ?? ''));
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(image2Key ?? 
     '', image2?.path ?? ''));
    }
  request.headers.addAll(header);
  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
  final respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();
  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
    return response.statusCode;
  } 
} 
catch (exception) {
  client.close();
  throw AppException.exceptionHandler(exception);
  }
}
```